# Cross join optimizations on AWS Glue/Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, optimization, cross-join

I have 2 dataframes:

df1 - 7 columns (IDs and VARCHARs), rows: 1,700,000

df2 - 7 columns (IDs and VARCHARs), rows: 25,000

Need to find all possible similarities, no way to skip cartesian-product.

AWS Glue: Cluster with 10 (or 20) G.1X Workers

Already tested for 178 partitions (Spark calculated on fly when filtered df1 from bigger df)
Running time: 10 hours... I stopped the job!
But on S3, more than 999 part-XXX-YYYYY files were found.

Question: How to optimize this cross join on Glue/Spark, if no way to skip cross-join?

Comment: Did you try broadcast ? if broadcast is failing due to memory issue ,try using G2X worker type.

Comment: I've tried. The same thing actually +/-.

Comment: And would be better to estimate, how long(hours) should this job be run with specified  cluster-size? Is there any method?

Answer (score 2):

With below approach and Glue configuration, Job completed in 121 min:

**Glue Details**=>

**Workers**=>G2.X

**Number of Workers**=> 50 . You could try with 149 also, this should complete job in 35-45 Min.

I have created two files:-

df1=> 7 columns rows: 1700000, size 140 MB (Based on column size, file size may be different for you)

df2=> 7 columns rows: 25000, size 2 MB

Now I have partitioned first dataframe with 42500.

How did I get the 42500-> First I have created DF1 with 1 records, DF2 with 25000 and saved, cross join output.

It was 3.5 MB file, For best performance, Optimum partition should be around 128 MB.
Lets assume you want to make one partition size as 150 MB.

Now output generated from 1 record was 3.5 MB, to make 150 MB partition size
we need approx. 42 records per partitions.
We have 1700000 records, which makes it approx. 40500 partitions.

For you, size for 1 record could differ. Use same approach to calculate partition size.
After the reparation, just use cross join with broadcast.

```
df1.reparition(40500)

df.crossJoin(broadcast(df2))
```

Comment: Hmm... So you tested it on your side, you got the result in 121 min (50 T2.X workers ~ 100 DPUs). You should be billed: $0.44 * (121/10 min) * (100 DPU) = $0.44*12*100 = $528

Does it sound right?

Comment: Or you should be billed: $0.44 * 2(hour) * (100 DPU) = $0.44*2*100 = $88

Comment: Sorry,  I dont have access to billing matrix. Ideally it should be $88, I have tested it on client account, as per them "We have very very low rate compare to standard pricing".

Comment: Thanks!  What about estimation of execution time of Spark job? Without(before) running the job to estimate/calculate approximately.

Comment: There is no such way to estimate execution time.The only way I can think of is, use previous stats  and estimate it.

Comment: As these are long running jobs, You could set max execution time, to avoid overbilling due to stuck jobs.

Comment: Hmm, you are about AWS Glue JOB settings? 
"Job timeout
Sets the maximum execution time in minutes. The default is 2880 minutes. If this limit is greater than the execution time, the job run state changes to “TIMEOUT”."

Comment: Yes.Although I am not sure if 2880 Minutes is correct value for your case.